# Trying to align my embed photo gallery (coming from tinymce editor) at center of my modal div

Tags: php, html, css, tinymce

Im using tinymce to insert news into a website.

I inserting a embed code that corresponds to a photo gallery in tinymce html editor. (Im using an online photo sharing service for my images gallery.)

This service give me a "embed code" and when I insert in my tinymce html editor I get this in my html: (my embed tag becomes a object tag)

```
<p>
<object style="height: 350px; width: 460px;" width="460" height="350" 
align="middle" 
data="http://flash.picturetrail.com/pflicks/3/spflick.swf" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">  
<param name="src" value="http://flash.picturetrail.com/pflicks/3/spflick.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="flashvars"    value="ql=2&amp;
src1=http://pic20.picturetrail.com:80/VOL1566/13680586/flicks/1/9035174" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain" />
</object>
</p>
```

And now Im trying to align my photo gallery at center of my modal div, but  Im not having sucess doing this.

Because I also need to float:left my photo gallery because if my paragraph text is too small my photogallery is coming to stick my paragraph text and I dont want that.

I want always a margin-top of 20px below my news image with .img class.

Do you know how can I solve this?

This is my fiddle with full example: http://jsfiddle.net/65z7w3z3/

This is how I show my textarea content in website;

```
echo '<p>'.$result_read_textarea['content_textarea'].'</p>';
```

**My Html:**

```
<div class="modal">
    <h2>Title of my first news</h2>
    <span id="date">15/08/2014</span><br />
    <img class="img" src=""/>
    <p>my first paragraph</p>
   <embed src="http://flash.picturetrail.com/pflicks/3/spflick.swf" 
   quality="high" FlashVars="ql=2&src1=http://pic20.picturetrail.com:80/VOL1566/13680586/flicks/1/9035174" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="" width="460" height="350" name="Acrobat Cube" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" style="height:350px;width:460px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
   </embed>

    <div id="pdfs">
        <h3>Links:</h3>
        <ul class="links"> 
            <li> <a href="'">Link 1</a></li>
            <li> <a href="'">Link 2</a></li>
            <li> <a href="'">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="close">Back</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because are floating the element. Remove the float. Also add a clear div to help with your layout too. The clear div will stop it floating up with your other elements.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/david321312312231/65z7w3z3/1/

CSS Update

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#pdfs, embed
{
    margin:20px auto;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML Update

```
// html code

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<embed // more html code
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vector. But its not working. I think that its because my paragraph and also my photogallery are coming from my text area so your solution with clearfix below my paragraph seems that dont result because my photogallery should be first than clear fix div...

Comment: Vector, sorry to boring you again. But dont you really know how can I do this dinamically? Your solution works. But my pragraph text and my embed gallery are in the same textarea, and Im showing this two elements like echo '<p>'.$result_read_textarea['content_textarea'].'</p>';

Comment: what does the output html look like within `$result_read_textarea['content_textarea']`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a wrapper div around the embed tag and align that to center:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 460px; margin: 0px auto;">...</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65z7w3z3/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your solution also dont works! Because my photogallery is coming from tinymce editor and I show what user writes in textarea like <p>'.$sql_read_result['textareacontent'].'</p>, So I dont know where to put that wrapper div..

Answer (score 0):

Create a  tag around your Gallery then style it.

**HTML Gallery Section:**

```
<div class="photogallery">
  <embed src="http://flash.picturetrail.com/pflicks/3/spflick.swf" 
   quality="high" FlashVars="ql=2&src1=http://pic20.picturetrail.com:80/VOL1566/13680586/flicks/1/9035174" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="" width="460" height="350" name="Acrobat Cube" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" style="height:350px;width:460px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
   </embed>
</div>
```

**CSS for Photo Gallery:**

```
.photogallery {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```